# Screen flashes when changing background image (hover)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Simple idea. Page has a background image. When user hovers over some link, the image changes.

Here's the implementations: http://www.goel.io/ (hover over social links)

You'll notice a flash. I know that's because data transfer and rendering takes a small but noticeable time. Also, you can notice that during the image change, the new image is it's own original size and then resizes to the full screen.

[image]

This is the code for setting the background image:

```
.bg {
    content: "";
    z-index: -1;
    position: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(/images/schemes/orange.svg);
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    transition: all 0.4s linear
}
```

And here's the code that changes the bg:

```
$(".btn-blog").mouseover(function(e) {
    $(".bg").css("background-image", "url(/images/schemes/orange.svg)");
});
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff and looked at a bunch of things. Nothing seemed relevant.

Any ideas on how to fix these 2 issues?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.fadeTo()` , `Array.prototype.concat()` `Array.prototype.splice()`

```js
$(function() {
  $.fx.interval = 0;
  (function(bg, btn) {
    btn.mouseover(function(e) {
      bg.fadeTo(75, 0.9, "linear", function() {
        bg.fadeTo(75, 1.0, "linear", function() {
          var img = bg.css("backgroundImage").split(", ");
          img = img.concat(img[0]).splice(1, 4).join(",");
          bg.css("backgroundImage", img)
        });
      })
    })
  }($(".bg"), $(".btn-blog")));
})
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  /* 100% */
  height: 100%;
  /* 100% */
  display: block;
  opacity: 1.0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%, 0px, 0px, 0px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature"), url("http://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats"), url("http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports"), url("http://lorempixel.com/300/300/technics");
  -webkit-transition: background-image -150ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-image -150ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-image -150ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-image -150ms linear;
  transition: background-image -150ms linear;
}
.btn-blog {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 39%;
  top: 10px;
  width: 120px;
}
.btn-blog:hover {
  cursor: wait;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg">
  <span class="btn-blog">hover</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Link prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ)

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/images/schemes/orange.svg">
```

But it doesn't work cross browser, so a safer way might be to load them as part of the page but hidden with css, if you do not wish to have the "flashing"

Comment: But `prefetch` would work only if all the images are in the DOM on page load. But in my case, it's not.

Comment: look at the example in the page, `<link rel="next" href="2.html">`, it's purpose is to fetch future resources during idle time, that can even be the next html page that users are most likely to visit. But if it's not done correctly, you are wasting user's bandwidth

Comment: I went with hiding the image in DOM. But there's still the issue where image is it's real size and then switches to the full screen size. http://i.imgur.com/zcMXWRF.gif

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make use of a css sprite and change the background image on :hover?